# Cant iterate SQL data with php to html table 'td' with out it becoming a mess

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, laravel, drupal

Im trying to make a table with data from Mysql database using PHP
Im trying to iterate data to the head part of the table and the body part of the table
so that if I will add data to my 'divesities' table or 'items' in my MYSQL database it will automatically be updated.
Does anyone know how can I iterate data to 2nd column without making a mess.
the first iterated column in my table seems ok its when i try to iterate to the second column called beers that the table starts becoming a mess.

```
<?php include 'tpl/header.php' ?>
<?php include 'dbconnect.php'?>

<a style="margin-left:300px;margin-top:-200px" href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
                <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
                Add User 
    
            </a>
<table class="table table-bordered" style="margin-left:300px;margin-top:40px; border: 2px solid grey; width:50%">

<thead>
<tr>
<?php foreach($db->query("SELECT name FROM diversities WHERE id =1") as $row):?>
<th><?=$row['name']?></th>
<?php endforeach;?>
<?php foreach($db->query("SELECT name FROM diversities WHERE id =2") as $row):?>
<th><?=$row['name']?></th>
<?php endforeach;?>
<?php foreach($db->query("SELECT name FROM diversities WHERE id =3") as $row):?>
<th><?=$row['name']?></th>
<?php endforeach;?>

</tr>



</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
<?php foreach($db->query("SELECT name FROM items WHERE CATALOG_NUM =1 LIMIT 3") as $row):?>
<td><?=$row['name']?></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach;?>


</tbody>

</table>





<?php include 'tpl/footer.php' ?>
```